# Реализация в Java сигнатуры метода?

Tags: java, методы

Как этот метод реализовать на java. 
Нужен для того чтобы проверить кодировку файлов на битовом уровне.
**Код:**

```
unc ::IsUTF8(unc *cpt) { if (!cpt) return 0;

if ((*cpt & 0xF8) == 0xF0) { // start of 4-byte sequence
    if (((*(cpt + 1) & 0xC0) == 0x80)
     && ((*(cpt + 2) & 0xC0) == 0x80)
     && ((*(cpt + 3) & 0xC0) == 0x80))
        return 4;
}
else if ((*cpt & 0xF0) == 0xE0) { // start of 3-byte sequence
    if (((*(cpt + 1) & 0xC0) == 0x80)
     && ((*(cpt + 2) & 0xC0) == 0x80))
        return 3;
}
else if ((*cpt & 0xE0) == 0xC0) { // start of 2-byte sequence
    if ((*(cpt + 1) & 0xC0) == 0x80)
        return 2;
}
return 0;
}
```

**Вопрос:**

- Как трансформировать этот метод в
     Java code?

Comment: @nazar_art, а ведь в utf-8 могут быть и 5-ти и 6-и байтовые последовательности, да и 1 байт (беззнаковый) меньший 128 это тоже правильная utf-8 кодировка.

Кстати, количество старших "единичных" бит в первом байте - это как раз размер в байтах этого utf-8 "символа".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

постарался максимально облегчить вашу задачу:

```
// на счет значения не уверен, подставьте нужное
private static final int UTF8_HEADER_SIZE = 8 ;

public static boolean isUTF8 (String path) {
    return isUTF8(new File(path)) ;
}

public static boolean isUTF8 ( File file ) {
    // validate input
    if (null == file) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("input file can't be null");
    }
    if (file.isDirectory ()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("input file refers to a directory");
    }

    // read input file
    byte [] buffer = new byte[UTF8_HEADER_SIZE];
    try {
        readBytes(file, buffer) ;
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Can't read input file, error = " + e.getLocalizedMessage () );
    }

    // validate file header
    // TODO: your validation goes here
    // if (0xF0 == (buffer[0] & 0xF8) ) {
    // }
    return false ;
}

private static void readBytes ( File input, byte[] buffer  ) throws IOException {
    if (null == buffer || 0 == buffer.length) {
        return;
    }

    // read data
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ( input ) ;
    fis.read ( buffer ) ;
    fis.close ();        
}
```

Comment: @jmu Супер расписано! Инкапсуляция ++. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @jmu // if (0xF0 == (buffer[0] & 0xF8) ) { => здесь заменил на if ((buffer[0] & 0xF8) == 0xF0) { if (((buffer[1] & 0xC0) == 0x80) && ((buffer[2] == 0x80) && ((buffer[3] == 0x80)))) return true; = и проверка не прошла. Вопрос почему так? В чем проблема как исправить?(при том что файл 100% нужного формата)

Comment: [EncodindsCheck](http://pastebin.com/c27wfZYK) - здесь начиная с if ((buffer[0] & 0xF8) == 0xF0) {... => start wrong.

Comment: @jmu добавил правильный метод, как ответ ниже. Там можно просто по 4 байта читать и все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите.

1. Для массивов в Java используется класс `ArrayList<Byte>`.
2. Битовые операции те же, только для беззнакового сдвига влево используется `>>>` (но вам это не нужно).
3. Вместо адресной арифметики применяйте индексирование.
4. Передать что-то типа указателя в середину массива невозможно, просто передавайте массив и начальный индекс.

Сигнатура:

```
// внутри класса
public static int IsUTF8(ArrayList<Byte> cpt, int startIndex)
{
    // ...
```

Дальше сами :-)

Comment: Мне туда нужно файл передать, и проверить. Пробую сейчас в методе public int byteSequence(File file) { 
if (file == null || (!file.isFile())) 
return 0; 
if ((cpt.charAt(0) & 0xF8) == 0xF0) { // start of 4-byte sequence 
if (((cpt.charAt(1) & 0xC0) == 0x80)...
Что скажете?

Comment: эээ... а где вы читаете файл? я бы разделил на две процедуры: чтение файла (например, <http://stackoverflow.com/a/8432074/276994>) и IsUTF8. (тем более, если я правильно понимаю, можно прочитать только начало файла.)

Comment: @VladD Так и надо это просто макет на скорую руку.

Comment: а откуда вы у массива взяли функцию charAt?

Comment: public int byteSequence(File file) => Тут брал как с файла

Comment: Ничего не понял, если честно. Какого типа у вас `cpt`? Массивы индексируются квадратными скобками, как везде.

Answer (score 1):

После непростого поиска, результат (сын ошибок трудных :) ) проверки кодировки UTF-8:

```
class EncodingsCheck implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        return isUTF8(currentFile);
    }

    public static boolean isUTF8(File file) {
        // validate input
        if (null == file) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input file can't be null");
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "input file refers to a directory");
        }

        // read input file
        byte[] buffer;
        try {
            buffer = readUTFHeaderBytes(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Can't read input file, error = " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (0 == (buffer[0] & 0x80)) {
            return true; // ASCII subset character, fast path
        } else if (0xF0 == (buffer[0] & 0xF8)) { // start of 4-byte sequence
            if (buffer[3] >= buffer.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((0x80 == (buffer[1] & 0xC0)) && (0x80 == (buffer[2] & 0xC0))
                    && (0x80 == (buffer[3] & 0xC0)))
                return true;
        } else if (0xE0 == (buffer[0] & 0xF0)) { // start of 3-byte sequence
            if (buffer[2] >= buffer.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((0x80 == (buffer[1] & 0xC0)) && (0x80 == (buffer[2] & 0xC0))) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (0xC0 == (buffer[0] & 0xE0)) { // start of 2-byte sequence
            if (buffer[1] >= buffer.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if (0x80 == (buffer[1] & 0xC0)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static byte[] readUTFHeaderBytes(File input) throws IOException {
        // read data
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(input);
        try{
            byte firstBytes[] = new byte[4];
            int count = fileInputStream.read(firstBytes);
            if(count < 4){
                throw new IOException("Empty file");
            }
            return firstBytes;
        } finally {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы проверяете `buffer.Length` в `isUTF8`? В силу вашего алгоритма это константа 4, по идее.